# How to programmatically change the weight of children in a taxonomy vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to edit an existing vocabulary to change the weight of the children. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `weight` property on the term object.

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid); //$tid = your taxonomy term id
$term->weight = 10000; //Whatever weight value
taxonomy_save_term($term);
```